# Data Explorer: Shrink query window a little more

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, user-interface, data-explorer, accessibility

The [**"Query Window" textbox** on data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) is already [stretchable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21229224/8112776), but it would be helpful if the ***minimum* height** were set *"even smaller"*.

When testing quick edits to a query, it would be nice to see the first few results (and any warnings), without constantly shaving to scroll up/down.

I *shrink* the query window as much as it lets me, but it's *not quite far enough...*

[image: can't *quite* see the results]

I *zoom out* on the browser window but then it gets harder to read, on a laptop screen, with *"aging eyesight"*, especially after "too many hours" in front of the screen.

## Actual Size:

[image: zoomed out]

OK Fine, it's not ***that*** small, but it kinda *feels* like that, and I assume that the minimum height is a pretty easy change.  (Is there a reason there even have to *be* a minimum?)

[image: Gramma Internet]